# OpenCV failing to import on MacOS

Tags: python, opencv

I've installed OpenCV from miniconda using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`.

However, every time I try to import it using `import cv2`, I get the following error message:

[image]

Could someone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: try: pip install opencv-python

Comment: I second the above recommendation. looks like a conda/anaconda problem. their packages are sub-standard.